# Delete parent folder with empty specific subfolder

Tags: powershell

I have multiple parent folders with defined subfolders structure:

- C:\parent1\Sub1
- C:\parent1\Sub2
- C:\parent1\ ...
- C:\parent2\Sub1
- C:\parent2\Sub2
- C:\parent2\ ...

I need to delete all parent folders in which subfolder named 'Sub2' is empty.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Are all parent folders located at the root of C:\? You should attempt this yourself with code and provide us with where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do exactly this. The $path variable contains the location where the parent folders are

```
$path = 'C:\'
$parentfolders = Get-Childitem $path -Directory 
foreach ($parentfolder in $parentfolders){
    foreach ($childfolder in (Get-Childitem $($parentfolder.FullName) -Directory )){
        if ($childfolder.Name -eq "Sub2"){
            if((Get-Childitem $($childfolder.FullName) | Measure-Object).Count -ne 0){
                Remove-Item -Path $($parentfolder.FullName) -Force -Recurse
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I combined my answer with the one from  Dave Sexton

```
$path = 'C:\'
    $parentfolders = Get-Childitem $path 
    foreach ($parentfolder in $parentfolders){
        Get-ChildItem -Filter Sub* -Recurse | ? {(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName).Count -eq 0} | % {Remove-Item $_.Parent -Recurse} 

    }
```

Comment: Without specifying `-Directory`, the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet also returns FileInfo objects. For all of those your foreach will fail. Also, why uset `Get-Childitem` 3 times where all folders have a common root?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in the root folder:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter Sub* -Recurse | ? {((Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName).Count -eq 0) -and $_.Name -eq 'Sub2'} | % {Remove-Item $_.Parent -Recurse}
```

Comment: This is only for one folder, he has multiple parent folders

Comment: Don't understand your comment - this will remove multiple parents.